# Are Z3's previous releases also on MIT license?

Tags: z3

I found the previous releases (tags) on github say "Z3 is licensed under MSR-LA (Microsoft Research License Agreement)".

My question is whether they are also on MIT license now. Could you kindly please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the legal world of licenses, but to be on the safe side I would assume that previous releases carry the old license since that's what's included in distribution packages.

Comment: And there also probably are no reasons to go with an old version, from a technical point of view too.